# Disable grub menu display on LCD and display only on serial console

Tags: grub

Currently I have Intel board with CentOS Linux on it.

When I switch on board, grub option is displayed on LCD Panel and also serial console(minicom attached to the board).

My requirement is:
When I switch on the board, grub menu should display only on serial but not on LCD display.

Please help me.